# Retrieve image path saved by UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, filepath, uiactivityviewcontroller

User can save images on UIImageView into library using `UIActivityViewController` sheet and also share or post it into social media as seen below:

[image]

If user selects "Save Image", UIActivityViewController has no way i know to return saved image path. It will just save and dismiss silently.

How could i retrieve the path where it is saved? I will be storing the path to access saved images and display them in another view. Thank you very much for any help.

EDIT: Below is how i present UIActivityViewController when user tapped on share button.

```
let imageShare = [ self.imageView.image ]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageShare as [Any] , applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.shareButton.frame

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: please add your code as well! How you are using UIActivityViewController?

Comment: I added it, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is: Since you already have the image... ***Why*** do you want to get that path?

However - you can get the selected "share" activity in the `UIActivityViewController` completion:

```
func shareImage(_ img: UIImage) -> Void {
    
    let items = [img]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.shareButton.frame

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed:
                                        Bool, arrayReturnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
        if completed {
            if let act = activityType {
                switch act {
                case .saveToCameraRoll:
                    print("Save Image was selected")
                    // do something here
                    // such as getting the asset reference?
                    //  or getting the URL to the asset?
                
                case .copyToPasteboard:
                    print("Copy was selected")
                    
                default:
                    print("Something else...")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Cancel was selected")
        }
        if let shareError = error {
            print("error while sharing: \(shareError.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
    
    present(activityViewController, animated: true)
    
}
```

So, depending on what you really want, you can easily find example code for getting the most recently saved image from the camera roll (or its asset reference, or URL, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am actually aware that we can access completed activity type when image is saved, but im not sure how to get that image's path. Accessing to recently saved image might not be the accurate way to retrieve it because, there could be some other image getting saved into library meanwhile; technically possible.

Comment: @UmitKaya - then, I guess, the question remains... why? What are you planning to do with the path reference, if you could reliable get it?

Comment: I would like to retrieve those pics saved and display to user in some other view as what is saved.